# Calling overriden sub-method inside super() method

Tags: python, inheritance, micropython

I need some help regarding super() method.
Consider this example:

```
class A:
    def subMethod(self):
        return "a"
    def callMe(self):
        print(self.subMethod())

class B(A):
    def subMethod(self):
        return "b"
    def callMe(self):
        print("Look at me")
        super().callMe()
```

Now, If I call `B.callMe()` it prints `a`. I want it to print `b`
How can I resolve this? Is it possible?

As for details, I'm using this code on MicroPython platform, so I'm limited in use of some high-level libraries, as it only contains couple of standard libs.

Heres real example:

```
class UARTbase():
    def readLine(self):
        pass

    def readWithSign(self):
        c = self.readLine()
        self.printDebug("raw")
        self.printDebug(c)
        c = c.decode()
        self.printDebug("decoded")
        self.printDebug(c)
        self.writeNoAck(c)
        return c


class UARTesp(UARTbase):
    def disableTermDecorator(func):
        def aFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return_value = None
            if(self.__term_count == 0):
                uos.dupterm(None, 1)
                self.getUart().init(timeout=self.TIMEOUT)
            self.__term_count = self.__term_count + 1
            try:
                return_value = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                self.printDebug("Error in wrapper")
                self.printDebug(e)
            self.__term_count = self.__term_count - 1
            if(self.__term_count == 0):
                self.getUart().init(timeout=0)
                uos.dupterm(self.getUart(), 1)
            return return_value
        gc.collect()
        return aFunc


    @disableTermDecorator
    def readLine(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = self.getUart().readline()
        if(c is not None):
            return c[:-2]
        # for compatibilty
        return b''

    @disableTermDecorator
    def readWithSign(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().readWithSign(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, I only need to call super, so I can wrap methods with this specific decorator.

When I call `super().readWithSign()` says that `c` is `None`, which it shouldn't be, in any case.

Comment: You can't call `B.callMe()`, as it is an instance method, which requires an object `objB = B()`. If you call `objB.callMe()` it should print 'b'

Comment: That does print 'b'. [Example](https://ideone.com/rNGXUk)

Comment: Ofc, I don't call it directly on class, I wrote it like that to be brief. I'll update with real example so you can see how I need to use it.

Comment: The whole point of overriding a method is that it should take precedence, even when called from the parent class. This allows you to write general code in the parent and delegate details to the child.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I forgot infamous `return` from `super()`.
Code:

```
    @disableTermDecorator
    def readWithSign(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().readWithSign(*args, **kwargs)
```